# adding NSMutableDictionary to NSMutableDictionary adds dictionaries as string

Tags: ios, nsmutabledictionary

I'm adding items from one nsmutabledictionary to another nsmutabledictionary but the dictionaries are been add it as string values and not as dictionaries. Here is my code:

```
// mainDictionary contains dictionaries
NSMutableDictionary *result=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
for (id key in mainDictionary) {
    [result  addEntriesFromDictionary:[mainDictionary objectForKey:key]];
    NSLog(@"type of class %@", NSStringFromClass([[result valueForKeyPath:@"key"] class]));
}
```

the output of NSLog is the following:

```
type of class __NSCFString
```

My question is how can add the dictionaries to the new dictionary keeping the integrity of the dictionaries ?

I'll really appreciate you help

Comment: I'm a little confused about the data structure here. Is this `mainDictionary` supposed to be a dictionary containing dictionaries containing dictionaries?

Comment: that is correct. mainDictionary contains dictionaries

Comment: Just try `[result  addEntriesFromDictionary:mainDictionary];` (Just in case `mainDictionary` is the desired dictionary that you want to add into the other dictionary.

Comment: I have a feeling the `NSLog` is telling you the wrong thing. Try replacing `[result valueForKeyPath:@"key"]` with `[result objectForKey:key]` and see what happens...?

Comment: @danypata thanks this made the trick [result addEntriesFromDictionary:mainDictionary]

Comment: I added my comment as an answer, if you like, you can accept it ;)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a problem in the posted code. The OP was wrong about his data structure. It won't be helpful for other people. Or: "too localized"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try `[result addEntriesFromDictionary:mainDictionary];` without the `for` loop. (Just in case mainDictionary is the desired dictionary that you want to add into the other dictionary